# How can I set equals function in objective of solver in R/Python?

Tags: python, r, solver

I am exploring one of the business problem to convert into solver/optimize problem.I have objective to set sum of 3 different columns should be exact 0.
As far I know Maximize and Minimize function problems can be solved using different available libraries.
SO looking forward to get help how can I set objective function equals to 0 and which package or libraries can be used?

Comment: May be you are looking for a constraint instead of an objective. It may also be just a system of equations instead of an optimization problem.

Comment: Is it possible to use any package where I can set value of objective equals to 0 instead of minimize or maximize it like in excel we can set value to 0

Comment: Use a solver for systems of equations, or alternatively add a constraint that limits the objective value.